# Good way to show hidden action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I want to add an overlay ActionBar to my app, that is hidden by default, since I do not have enough space on the screen to show it all the time.

Now I am wondering about a good way to make the action bar appear, more precisely what input element I should offer to the user to unhide the action bar.

Is there a "correct" Android way to do this? I was thinking about showing the overflow button, even when the Action Bar is hidden and use it to show the Action Bar like this:

[image]

Is this a bad idea and why? What would be the way to implement it? A new button in the layout, or is there a way to only show the overflow button and have the rest of the Action Bar hidden?

I am using the Action Bar from the support library v7.

Answer (score 2):

Check the [Overlaying the Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html) training document. It explains how to show/hide the action bar using "overlay mode".

Comment: I understand how to create the overlayed ActionBar, nevertheless I am looking for a intuitive way to tell the user "click here if you want the ActionBar to appear".

Comment: AFAIK there is nothing in the Design guide about this. But (re)using the overflow icon does eem like a good idea.